# Does Aerospike support rank functions?

Tags: window-functions, aerospike

I am evaluating Aerospike and one of the requirements that i have is the support for rank function (RowNumber , Rank , DenseRank , Ntile). I tried to find it but couldnt succeed.

Can you help me out whether the rank function support is there in Aerospike? if not, How do I implement rank function in Aerospike? Any reference docs will also help.

Answer (score 1):

no, there is no rank function in the product as of now.  You could initiate a scan and do the sorting on the client side perhaps.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Map](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) data type was extended to support KV_ORDERED operations, aka SortedMap. This was initially added in release [3.8.4](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.8.4) (June 17 2016) and announced GA in release [3.10.0.3](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.10.0.3) (October 21 2016).

There's a rich [map operations API](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map-ops.html) that includes rank functions.  The various language clients support map operations.